# How to re-render state when React useState changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, setstate

We have the initial `useEffect()` being called to get all the data from the API.

```
const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);
const [filteredItems, setFilteredItems] = React.useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URI + "item/getAll", { headers: auth }).then((res) => {
        setItems(res.data);
        setFilteredItems(res.data);
    })
    axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URI + "role/getAll", { headers: auth }).then((res) => {
        setRoles(res.data);
    })
}, [])
```

Than an `OnChange` occurs which triggers the `handleFilters()` method. This method checks if the `item` has the same `role` as specified. If it does, put it in a temporary array. Lastly set the `filteredItems` to the **new** `filteredItems`.

```
function handleFilters() {
    let tempArray = [];
    items.forEach((item) => {
        if (item.role.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(role.toLowerCase()) && !tempArray.includes(item)) {
            tempArray.push(item);
        }
    })
    setFilteredItems(tempArray);
}
```

These `filteredItems` are rendered in the return. Like this

```
return (
    //handleFilters() is triggered here
    {filteredItems.map((item, index) => (
        <Box key={index} sx={{ ":hover": { backgroundColor: "#F5F5F5" } }}>
            //etc do stuff with the item properties
        </Box>
    ))}
)
```

Now the problem is, that when I set some filters and trigger the `handleFilters()` method. The `filteredItems` doesn't change instantly, instead they get changed the NEXT time `handleFilters()` is triggered. Which means that the render is always one step too late.

I also tried to put `filteredItems` in the useEffect empty array, but that doesn't work. I think it's because the axios call is also getting executed which resets the `filteredItems` back to all items.

Solution: that `if(!tempArray.includes(item))` was just bad coding on my part, because `forEach` only goes through all the elements once and there are no duplicates. Thanks to XH栩恒 I came up with the solution.

```
const filteredItemRoles = !role ? itemRoles : itemRoles.filter(item => {
    return item.role.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(role.toLowerCase());
})
```

Comment: what do you mean by when I set some filters?

Comment: Can you show your whole file code(or component) in one snippet rather than breaking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do if I need a filter. I am assuming you have a dropdown select to change the selected role (`role`) variable.

```
const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);
const [role, setRole] = React.useState(null);
const [roles, setRoles] = React.useState([]);
const filteredItems = items
                        .filter(item => {
                            return item.role.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(role?.toLowerCase())
                        })
                        .filter((item, index, array) => {
                            return !array.includes(item)
                        })
```

In the first filter function, you can see the variable `role` is used, that is your selected role. When you selected role is changed, it will re-render the page as `role` is with `useState`. When it re-render, the `filteredItems` will also be re-construct while the `items` still remain from the `useEffect` hook

Answer (score 0):

I think this has already happened to me and the solution for me was to wrap the function in a `useCallback()` hook with `items` and `setFilteredItems` in the dependency array:

```
const handleFilterItems = useCallback(() => {
 // your filtering logic
 },[items, setFilteredItems])
```

Does this help?

Comment: I modified the `handleFilters()` to be a `const` and use a callBack but `filteredItems` (in your example `items` is still empty when I put a `console.log` at the place where u put `// your filtering logic`